# MAIN not executed by Factor on command line

Tags: factor-lang

I'm not seeing any output from my Hello World program.

```
$ cat hello.factor 
USE: io
IN: hello

: hello ( -- ) "Hello World!" print ;

MAIN: hello

$ factor hello.factor
$
```

(No output)

```
$ factor -run=hello
Vocabulary does not exist
name "hello"

$ factor -run=hello hello.factor 
$
```

(No output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor now executes a MAIN function for command line scripts that specify one. (See [GitHub](https://github.com/slavapestov/factor/commit/51489e3ef8f592faa75c0f78cf8e581596e73f93))

Answer (score 2):

`MAIN:` defines an entry point for a vocabulary when the vocabulary is passed to `run`, not necessarily when it is "loaded" from the command line, as you're doing above.  The easiest way to make this work is to simply issue `"hello" run` from the UI listener.

To actually call the `hello` word as a script, simply place a call in the top level, like so:

```
USE: io
IN: hello

: hello ( -- ) "Hello World!" print ;

! This is the important part
hello
```

Alternatively, you can load *and run* the vocabulary from the command line with the `-run=vocab` command line argument.  For instance, `factor -run=hello`.

There is some more information on this in the docs.  Try running `"command-line" about` in the listener.

Comment: Looks to be something with your vocabulary path.  Try ["Working with code outside of the Factor source tree
"](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-add-vocab-roots.html) in the Factor docs.  Generally, though, you can do a lot just from the UI listener.  Use the [Scaffold tool](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-tools.scaffold.html) to start your projects, then run them with `"my-vocab-name" run` from the listener.  To compile, use the [Deploy tool](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-tools.deploy.usage.html) from the listener.