# Factor shebangs

Tags: shebang, factor-lang

According to [Hyperpolyglot](http://hyperpolyglot.org/stack), Factor should accept shebangs. But on my system Factor can't handle shebangs.

Specs: Factor v0.94, Mac OS X 10.7

```
$ cat hello.factor 

\#!/usr/bin/env factor

USE: io
IN: hello

: hello ( -- ) "Hello World!" print ;

MAIN: hello

$ ./hello.factor 

./hello.factor

1: #!/usr/bin/env factor
                 ^
No word named “#!/usr/bin/env” found in current vocabulary search path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but the web page shows a space after the `#!`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env factor
```

If that doesn't work, it's likely that Hyperpolyglot got this wrong (or perhaps it refers to a different version or implementation of `factor`).

Amusingly, when I try the example on my system (Ubuntu), I get:

```
/usr/bin/factor: `./hello.factor' is not a valid positive integer
```

but that's because `/usr/bin/factor` is the GNU coreutils utility that factors numbers into primes.  8-)}

Comment: Thanks! With the shebang resolved, can you help me with this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101575/main-not-executed-by-factor-on-command-line

Comment: I would if I could, but I don't know the language, (it was the shebang tag that caught my eye).

Comment: This is the first language I've seen that requires a space between the `#!` and the rest of the arguments. Do you know of any other languages that need a space there? Erlang has severe restrictions on where shebangs can occur (only escript can handle shebangs, not the erl interpreter/compiler).

Comment: @mcandre: A lot of scripting languages allow the `#!` just as a side effect of their use of `#` to introduce a comment.  (Some will examine the contents of the shebang line; for example, Perl does this.)  Factor seems to use `!` to introduce comments.  I don't know enough about its syntax to figure out how it manages to ignore the `#! ` line.  This gets tricky because that first line is meaningful both to the kernel (which uses it to determine what to invoke) and to the language itself.  (To answer your question, I don't know.)

Comment: Factor normally accepts `!` as a comment, but `!#` is also defined as a comment.  That's definitely one cool thing about factor: the syntax is all in the documentation.  Search for `!#` in the docs and you can read all about it.

Comment: @kylc: Do you mean `#!` rather than `!#`?