# Does Factor have an equivalent to the Python idiom if __name__=="__main__": main()?

Tags: program-entry-point, factor-lang, scriptedmain

Factor appears to have a main method like any C-based language:

```
#! /usr/bin/env factor -script

USE: io
IN: hello

: hello ( -- ) "Hello World!" print ;

MAIN: hello
```

But Factor does not execute the main function automatically; if you run `./hello.factor` in a terminal, nothing happens because `main` isn't called.

Does anyone know if Factor has syntax like Python, so that `hello` is actually called on `./hello.py`?

```
def hello():
   print "Hello World!"

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MAIN not executed by Factor on command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101575/main-not-executed-by-factor-on-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor will now execute a `main` function if one is specified. You'll still have to edit `~/.factor-rc` to add the `INCLUDING`/`IN` macros so that Factor will search for code in the current directory.

~/.factor-rc:

```
! Andrew Pennebaker
! INCLUDING macro that imports source code files in the current directory

USING: kernel vocabs.loader parser sequences lexer vocabs.parser ;
IN: syntax

: include-vocab ( vocab -- ) dup ".factor" append parse-file append use-vocab ;

SYNTAX: INCLUDING: ";" [ include-vocab ] each-token ;
```

scriptedmain.factor:

```
#! /usr/bin/env factor

USING: io math.parser ;
IN: scriptedmain

: meaning-of-life ( -- n ) 42 ;

: main ( -- ) meaning-of-life "Main: The meaning of life is " write number>string print ;

MAIN: main
```

test.factor:

```
#! /usr/bin/env factor

INCLUDING: scriptedmain ;
USING: io math.parser ;
IN: test

: main ( -- ) meaning-of-life "Test: The meaning of life is " write number>string print ;

MAIN: main
```

Example:

$ ./scriptedmain.factor 
Main: The meaning of life is 42
$ ./test.factor 
Test: The meaning of life is 42

As posted on [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptedMain#Factor).